# Building a csv file to download from php site

Tags: php

Ive seen lots on this subject but haven't been able to get this to work myself.

I have a php page that is listing a bunch of users names and userids. I am trying to add a button that onclick will download a csv file with the columns name and userid populated with my list.
My array that i want to put into the csv file is built and comma separated for name and userid. I have a button that i am trying to get to execute a php script to build and download the csv

```
<input type="button" value="Export CSV" onclick="group-download.php">
```

My array is called $data here is an example of what it looks like if i do a print_r($data):

```
Array ( [0] => Joe Bloggs [1] => jbloggs [2] => Steve Jobs [3] => sjobs [4] => Steve wozniak [5] => swozniak )
```

and this is my group-download.php file

```
<?php 

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$_SESSION[client]_group.csv');
$data = $_POST["data"];
$output = fopen('php://output', 'wb');
fputcsv($output, array('Name', 'Username'));
foreach ($data as $line ) {
    $val = explode(",", $line);
    fputcsv(output, $val);
}
fclose($output);

?>
```

When i press my export button nothing is happening on screen and in the console log i am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: group is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't just name the script page as if it was a link. You could call the action page directly using `onclick="window.open('group-download.php', '_blank')"` or via ajax